# Defining macro script which acts according to mode; math or normal

Tags: macros

I want to create a macro say BOLDMATH such that whenever I use this macro it should do following:

if in equation environment or inline math mode then it should return \mathbf{.}
else it should return $\mathbf{.}$

I can use 2 macros but I want a compact one.

Comment: `\newcommand\BOLDMATH[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}`

Comment: In general, there is tex primitive `\ifmmode ... \else ... \fi` and LaTeX2e command `\TextOfMath{<text mode>}{<math mode>}`,

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was looking for shortcut to use mathbf instead of textbf. Although  it solved my problem, but I completely agree with your point that source code should be longer for clarity. Thanks

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I was unaware of what you mentioned. I looked and found it it very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, what you ask is frowned upon, because it removes the context in which the symbol is being used.  Generally, it is better to have a longer source document, if it helps to explain the context of the particular usage.

Nonetheless, you asked for it.  However, it is not a "best practice".

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\BOLDMATH[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
In text, \BOLDMATH{x}, and in math, $y=m\BOLDMATH{x}+b$.
\end{document}
```

[image]